# Adding workflow in site definition created using visual studio 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, site-definition

I am creating a site definition by code. I want to add an already created workflow to this site definition, then what are the steps to achieve this?

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your ONET.xml and add Site feature definition:

```
<Configurations>
  <Configuration ...>
    <SiteFeatures>
      <Feature ID="[guid-here]" />
      ...
    </SiteFeatures>
    ...
  </Configuration>
</Configurations>
```

For inspiration open any of existing site templates in your 14 hive directory:

Here is the STS C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\sts\xml